# How to show the usual topology is finer than co-finite topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have solved a bunch of problems where the basis is used to quickly deduce which topology is finer than which.

However, I do not know the basis of co-finite topology.

> What is the straight forward approach to compare the two topologies?

Proof attempt:

Let $U$ be an open set in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_{co-finite})$, then $\mathbb{R}\backslash U$ is finite.

We want to show that $U$ is in $((\mathbb{R},\tau_{usual})$

Let $x \in U$, then $U = \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} \{B_\epsilon(x)|\epsilon > 0\}$

Therefore $U$ is in $\tau_{usual}$

Let me know if there is some (or a lot) problem with the attempt, it's my first try

Comment: 1) Look up, if necessary, what the open sets are in the cofinite topology. 2) Show they are all open in the usual topology. 3) To show that the usual topology is strictly finer, name an open set in the usual topology that is not open in the cofinite topology.

Comment: (1). Error:  $U$ could be empty, so $R$  \  $U$  might not be finite. You should first say that we need only consider $\phi \ne U \ne R$ because $\phi$ and $R$ belong to every topology on $R .$.....  (2).  In your last line, what  is $\epsilon$ and what is its relation to $x$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few corrections:

First, if $U$ is open in the cofinite topology then $\Bbb R\setminus U$ is either finite *or* it is $\Bbb R$ itself (if $U = \emptyset$). There's no simpler description of a basis for the topology.

Second, it's not true that $U = \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} \{B_\epsilon(x)|\epsilon > 0\}$. For one thing, you probably mean $B_\epsilon(x) \setminus \{x\}$ not the entire ball $B_\epsilon(x)$, because $x\in B_\epsilon(x)$. For another, if $x\in U, y\notin U$, then $y \in B_\epsilon(x) \setminus \{x\}$ for some $\epsilon$.

An approach that works: Suppose $U$ is open in the cofinite topology. If $U=\Bbb R$ then $U$ is open in the usual topology, so suppose not. Then $\Bbb R \setminus U$ is finite, so in the usual topology it's closed, hence its complement $\Bbb R \setminus (\Bbb R \setminus U) = U$ is open.

To show that the two topologies are different, you need to find an open set in the usual topology that isn't open in the cofinite topology. Consider $U = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb N$. Thus, the usual topology is strictly finer.

Answer (score 6):

Since the open intervals form a basis of $\tau_\textsf{usual}$, it suffices to express $U$ as a union of open intervals. Indeed, since $\mathbb R \setminus U$ is finite, we know that for some $n \in \mathbb N$ and for some $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb R$ such that $x_1 < \cdots < x_n$, we have that:
$$
\mathbb R \setminus U = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \iff
U = (-\infty, x_1) \cup (x_1, x_2) \cup \cdots \cup (x_{n-1}, x_n) \cup (x_n, \infty)
$$
as desired.

Comment: Are $ \mathbb R \setminus U$ and $\mathbb R - U$ both shows compliment of $U$ in $\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your notation $\bigcup_{x\in U}\{B_{\epsilon}(x) \mid \epsilon >0 \}$ doesn't make sense - what is $\epsilon$ here? Instead, you are almost right - for each $x \in U$ you must find **one** $\epsilon_x$ (possibly depending on $x$) so that $B_{\epsilon_x} \subset U$. Since the complement of $U$ is a finite set, you can choose $\epsilon_x$ as $\min \{|x-z| \mid z\in \mathbb R \setminus U \}$. The complement of U being a finite set forces this $\epsilon_x$ to be strictly positive (the min of a finite set of strictly positive numbers).